# "Согласно чему-то"

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "согласно чему-то"? Например: "Согласно правилам русского языка(,) "не" с глаголами пишется раздельно".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере запятая не нужна.
Оборот "согласно (тому-то)" как правило не обособляется. 
Возможно так называемое интонационное обособлние, обычно это происходит в очень длинных фразах, лишенных других знаков препинания.